# If each element in $A$ is greater than all elements in a unique subset of $B$, is the average of $A$ greater than average of $B$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, inequality

Suppose I have two sets $A = \{a_1, ..., a_n\}$ and $B = \{ b_1, ..., b_m\}$ of non-negative real numbers and where $a_1\geq a_2 \geq ... \geq a_n$, and $|A| < |B|$.

Now, suppose $B$ can be split into $n$ disjoint subsets $B_1,...,B_n$ such that

\begin{align}
|B_i| = \left\{ \begin{array}{cc} 
                \big\lfloor\frac{|B|}{|A|}\big\rfloor & \hspace{5mm} \text{if } i \text{ is odd} \\
                \big\lceil\frac{|B|}{|A|}\big\rceil & \hspace{5mm} \text{if } i \text{ is even} \\
                \end{array} \right.
\end{align}

and for all $i \in [1, n]$,  $$\ \ a_i \geq b \text{ for all } b \in B_i$$

Then is it true that
$$\frac{\sum_{a \in A} a}{|A|} \geq \frac{\sum_{b \in B} b}{|B|}?$$

Comment: There is a problem with your definition of $B_i$, for instance, if $|A|=3$, $|B|=5$, then the sum of all $B_i$ is not $B$.

Comment: Err.. but it's an assumption right? "Suppose $B$ can be split into ...."

so $|A| = 3, |B| = 5$ as a counterexample is also invalid?

Comment: @ Yes, not every $B$ can be split that way though.

Comment: Yea, so only $B$s that can split that way can be considered for counterexamples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The problem is rounding: even numbered sets may have more elements. For instance:
$$
A=\{1,1,0\},B=\{1,1,1,0\}
$$
Then, $|B_1|=1,|B_2|=2,|B_3|=1$, so we may choose $B_1=\{1\},B_2=\{1,1\},B_3=\{0\}$ and $a_1=1\ge 1=b_1$, $a_2=1\ge 1=b_2=b_3$, $a_3=0\ge 0=b_4$ but
$$
\frac{1}{|A|}\sum_{a\in A} a = \frac{2}{3} \ngeq \frac{3}{4}=\frac{1}{|B|}\sum_{b\in B} B 
$$

Comment: Er but that is not a valid counterexample? It doesnt satisfy the conditions.

$a_1 = 1$, and $|B_1| = 1$, that means $a_2 = 0$ should be greater than all elements in $B_2$, but $B_2$ has to be either $\{0, 1 \}$ or $\{1, 1 \}$, both doesnt satisfy the condition.

Comment: @Nicholas I have extended the answer to defined $B_1,B_2$.

Comment: If $B_2 = \{1, 1\}$, it doesnt satisfy the condition that $a_2 \geq b$ for all $b \in B_2$

Comment: @Nicholas Yes, it does. Maybe you meant the strict inequality ?

Comment: There's the condition that $a_1 \geq a_2$ also

Comment: @Nicholas Ah, OK, then I have to change the order

Comment: yea if the order is changed, the other condition ($a_2 \geq b$ for all $b \in B_2$) is broken

Comment: Thanks! Does a counterexample exist also for $$\frac{\sum_{a \in A} a}{|A|} \geq \frac{\sum_{b \in B} b}{|B| + 1}?$$